# SwingWorker creates multiple thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I don't know if I used SwingWorker correctly. In my requirements, I need to refreshed every seconds, so I need a SwingWorker that needs to execute every seconds.

A part of my code illustrated below on how I used to loop my SwingWorker.

```
// Parent class

/**
 * Initialize background services.
 */
private void initServices() {
        this.dtModel = (DefaultTableModel) tblHistory.getModel(); // Default data model of the jTable
        this.updateTimer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() { // I don't know if this is right, I use Timer to loop the Swingworker
            @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    new CallHistoryWatcherService(CallHistory.this, updateTimer, dtModel).execute();
                }
        });
        updateTimer.setRepeats(false);
    updateTimer.start();
}

// Watcher class

/**
 * Watch the CallInformations if any update has been made.
 * This will check every seconds.
 * @param history
 * @param updateTimer
 * @param dtModel 
 */
public CallHistoryWatcherService(CallHistory history, javax.swing.Timer updateTimer, DefaultTableModel dtModel) {
    // Initialize values
}

@Override
protected Collection<Vector> doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Collection<Vector> chunks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (CallInformations info : CallInformations.getCallInformations(OrderBy.Ascending)) {
        Vector v = new Vector();
                // Get from data from Database then place it to Vector
                chunks.add(v);
        }
        return chunks;
}

@Override
protected void done() {
        try {
        history.updateTableData(get()); // From parent class, manually update the data based on new Collection of data
        System.out.println("Call History refreshed...");
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        COLUMN_NAMES.clear();
        updateTimer.restart(); // Again, I don't know if this is right, restart the timer to execute the SwingWorker
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the Javadoc of [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html):

> There are three threads involved in the life cycle of a SwingWorker:
>
> - Current thread
> - Worker thread
> - Event Dispatch Thread

The background job is done on a single worker thread. But the internal implementation of `SwingWorker` uses a shared pool of threads via an `ExecutorService` to run the background jobs of multiple `SwingWorkers`. Quoting from Javadoc of `SwingWorker.execute()`:

> Schedules this SwingWorker for execution on a worker thread. There are a **number of worker threads** available.

So what you see is perfectly normal as those are the threads of the thread pool used by the `SwingWorker` internally.

**Edit:**

In your case I wouldn't use `SwingWorker`. I would just use a separate thread (not the EDT) to do the work, and once it's done, I would update the UI but in the EDT with a call of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`. And I would use a repeatable `Timer` to perform this job periodically.

Comment: I've edited my question and the code illustrated above.